# ImageMagick: How to set transparency color of an opaque overlay before composite?

Tags: imagemagick

Given: two PNG images without an alpha channel.

Only the `overlay.png` image should be inverted (hence the `-negate`) and all pure black in this image should be turned transparent before composing it over the other, unaltered `image.png`.

Moreover, I would like to do so in one command without generating intermediate images.

As an utter ImageMagick novice, I already managed to write the following. However, I have no clue where to put `-transparent black` now?

```
composite -gravity center \( -negate overlay.png \) image.png output.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a small break, I eventually found it; I have to use `convert` which happens to be much  more versatile than `composite`.

One caveat when using `convert` is that one needs to reverse the order of the images!

```
convert -gravity center image.png \( -negate overlay.png -transparent black \) -composite output.png
```